# Given a specific user I want to find all users having at least all of the roles this specific user has

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have `user_role` table having `user` and `role` columns.

```
| User | Role |
---------------
| 100  | 10   |
| 101  | 10   |
| 101  | 11   |
| 102  | 11   |
```

I want to write a query that will return users with same or lesser roles. For example:

- Return user 100 for user 100
- Return user 100,101,102 for user 101
- Return user 102 for user 102

**Business requirement:** Suppose User X belongs to Asia group only. So X should have access permission to users who belongs to Asia group only. But say Y belongs to Asia and Europe groups. So Y should have access permission to users who belongs to:

- Asia group only
- Europe group only
- Asia and Europe group only

Now, X should not access the data of Y as X does not belong to all the groups that Y belongs to. Similarly, say Z belongs to Asia, Europe and America. So, Z should access all the data of X, Y and Z but the reverse is not true.

**My initial SQL:**

```
select distinct(user) from user_role where role in
(select role from user_role where user=?);
```

Above query returns all the users sharing **at least one** common groups and not **all** common groups.

Can anybody please help me with a SQL example?

Comment: post the output ...question is not clear

Comment: you said *users with same or lesser roles* then why is that when searching for `102`, only `102` is returned? isn't it `100, 101, 102`? since `100` and `101` contains `role: 10` which is *lesser* than the `role` of `user: 102`?

Comment: @JohnWoo : By the phrase "users with same or lesser roles" I didn't mean numeric role numbers. Instead, I meant that users with all the roles the current user has. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected rows! select distinct(c1), c2... eq select distinct c1, c2... eq select distinct c1, (c2)...

Comment: I think you should rephrase your requirement to something like this: *Given a specific user I want to find all users having **at least** all of the roles this specific user has*.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - As suggested, I have updated the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with much more less effort. The idea is left join roles on roles of particular user and then filter only those users for which all roles are found in that particular user's roles:

```
;with c as(select roleid from userroles where userid=100)
select r.userid from userroles r left join c on r.roleid = c.roleid
group by r.userid
having sum(case when c.roleid is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bca579/7

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-- Create a CTE that will help us know the number of roles any user have.
;WITH CTE (UserId, RoleId, NumberOfRoles)
AS (
SELECT T1.UserId, RoleId, NumberOfRoles
FROM UsersToRoles T1 INNER JOIN
(
-- Derived table is needed so that we can have 
-- the user, he's roleId and he's number of roles in the CTE
SELECT UserId, COUNT(RoleId) As NumberOfRoles
FROM UsersToRoles 
GROUP BY UserId  
) T2 ON(T1.UserId =  T2.UserId)
)

-- We join the CTE with itself on the RoleId to get only users that have the same roles, 
-- and on the NumberOfRoles to ensure that the users we get back have at least the nomber of roles as the user we testing.
SELECT DISTINCT T1.UserId
FROM CTE T1 
INNER JOIN CTE T2 ON(T1.RoleId = T2.RoleId AND T1.NumberOfRoles <= T2.NumberOfRoles)
WHERE T2.UserId = @UserId
```

[Play with it yourself in this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/798ce/2)

CTE, or [Common Table Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) is a concept introduced in Sql Server 2008. basically, you define a select statement that the rest of your sql can refer to as if it was a view.

In this case, you could have this CTE written as a view and it would give you the same result.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! But, can you please also explain the query in detail?

Comment: @Tamal: Actually, now that I think about it, My answer is wrong. Giorgi's answer is better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726005/given-a-specific-user-i-want-to-find-all-users-having-at-least-all-of-the-roles/29728874#29728874